# Sphinx remove code formatting from custom code reference

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have the following classes:

```
class A:
    def x():
        """ Do the thing. """
class B(A):
    def x():
        """
        Do the thing, but better than the :py:meth:`parent <A.x>`
        """
```

The entire module is `autodoc`ed. I would like to have a link to the parent implementation of `x` that renders as "parent", not as "`parent`". How do I remove the code formatting from the custom method reference?

The link itself is interpreted correctly based on the first rule of [cross reference formats](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/inline.html#cross-referencing-syntax).

Here is the generated HTML for the link:

```
<a class="reference internal" href="#my_module.A.x" title="my_module.A.x">
    <code class="xref py py-meth docutils literal">
        <span class="pre">parent</span>
    </code>
</a>
```

[Line breaks inserted by me for legibility. Original HTML has no breaks or spaces between tags.]

I am using Sphinx 1.6.3 with Python 3.6.2 in an Anaconda environment.

Inverse question is here: [Sphinx add code formatting to :ref:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45741961/2988730)

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the HTML output? I think you might be able to add a custom style to your theme's CSS to make it appear as a normal, non-monospace font.

Comment: @StevePiercy. Done

Comment: AFAIK, Sphinx does not support custom styles for inline code. You could try CSS with a crazy selector, something like `a[href!#my_module.A.x]>code>span`, and a style that overrides the `pre` class with `!important`.

Comment: I am perfectly OK with defining a custom role for this. Something called `:py:methref:` for example. I will look into how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem.  The only solution I have found is to write:

```
"""
Do the thing, but better than the `parent <#my_module.A.x>`_
"""
```

which creates a regular ol' hyperlink to the `A.x` entry on the generated HTML page.  However, this only works for HTML output; other formats (e.g., LaTeX) will have broken links.